# How to create a macro in c++ with inside a String variable?

Tags: c++

I have in the past defined in the macro in the following way..

```
#define MACRO_NAME "devices/987654/bucket"
```

I would like to replace the number with a String variable `class String` in c++ .

How can I define a new macro with inside with string ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Make it a `String` (I suppose this is arduino, otherwise you'd be using `std::string`):

```
const String string_name = String("devices/") + the_number + String("/bucket");
```

Macros are expanded by the preprocessor as the first step of compilation. At that stage there are no variables or strings, only token.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want by using a macro function. Here is a small example using std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define MACRO_NAME(NUMBER, OUT){replaceNumber(NUMBER, OUT);}        

void replaceNumber(int32_t number, std::string &out){
    const std::string devices = "devices/";
    const std::string bucket = "/bucket";
    out = devices + std::to_string(number) + bucket;
}

int main()
{
    std::string name; 
    MACRO_NAME(213, name);
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```